# Parsec: parse string that satisfies some predicate

Tags: haskell, parsec

Parsec already have a `satisfy` parser which succeeds when a given predicate returns `True` when applied to given char:

```
punctuationOrSymbol = satisfy isPunctuation <|> satisfy isSymbol
```

How can I do something similar for a whole string? I need it because I want to parse an URI but only if it is valid. For that, I want to leverage [`isURI` function in `network-uri` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri-2.6.1.0/docs/Network-URI.html#v:isURI). Something like:

```
uri :: ParsecT s u m URI
uri = parseURI <$> satisfyForString isURI
```

I suspect that it has something to do with [`token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:token) function, but I'm new to Haskell and I haven't been able to understand it well.

Comment: How much input would you want `satisfyForString isURI` to read? Do you want it to read the largest prefix for which the predicate is true? That would mean going through the entire input, testing the predicate at each point, and then backtracking to the last point where the predicate was true. That would be pretty inefficient.

Comment: The parser needs to be applied to a very small section of a line, because a new line character is expected just after the URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ParsecT` is an instance of `Alternative`, so you can use `guard` to do something like this:

```
predicateP :: (a -> Bool) -> Parsec s u a -> Parsec s u a
predicateP pr p = do
   x <- p
   guard $ pr x
   return x
```

I wouldn't be surprised if that already existed as a combinator somewhere, but I'm not super familiar with `parsec`.

Now that only gives you a way to apply a predicate; To apply that to a string you'll have to get a string which you think is or might be a URL first. How you get that depends on your domain (when parsing XML you'll most likely find those in attributes or text contents for instance).

Comment: "I wouldn't be surprised if that already existed as a combinator somewhere" I believe that'd be `mfilter` from `Control.Monad`.